# can i compress a pandas dataframe into one row?

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that I've extracted from a json object using pd.json_normalize.
It has 4 rows and over 60 columns, and with the exception of the 'ts' column there are no columns where there is more than one value.
[image: screenshot of dataframe]

Is it possible to merge the four rows togather to give one row which can then be written to a .csv file? I have searched the documentation and found no information on this.
To give context, the data is a one time record from a weather station, I will have records at 5 minute intervals and need to put all the records into a database for further use.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get the desired result, it's a little convoluted, and i would expect that there is a much more succint way to do it, but I basically manipulated the dataframe, replaced all nan's with zero, replaced some strings with ints and added the columns together as shown in the code below:

```
    with open(fname,'r') as d:
    ws=json.loads(next(d)) 
    df=pd.json_normalize(ws['sensors'], record_path='data')
    df3=pd.concat([df.iloc[0],df.iloc[1], df.iloc[2], 
    df.iloc[3]],axis=1)
    df3.rename(columns={0 :'a', 1:'b', 2 :'c' ,3 :'d'}, inplace=True)
    df3=df3.fillna(0)
    df3.loc['ts',['b','c','d']]=0
df3.loc[['ip_v4_gateway','ip_v4_netmask','ip_v4_address'],'c']=int(0)
    df3['comb']=df3['a']+df3['b']+df3['c']+df3['d']
    df3.drop(columns=['a','b','c','d'], inplace=True)
    df3=df3.T
```

As has been said by quite a few people, the documentation on this is very patchy, so I hope this may help someone else who is struggling with this problem! (and yes, i know that one line isn't indented properly, get over it!)